# Dividing Several Values Against An Entire Row VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have coded a function in VBA that calculates a predefined exchange rate for a sales order. However I forgot to divide the calculated amount by the item quantity. I used a CDbl function to select the row of values and divide to it's corresponding item quantity. It works when there is only one row but not when multiple rows?

Can anyone provide a solution, code is below, thanks! Just to clarify - Range("V/U/W19") are the areas with the exchange rates defined.

```
With Sheets("Paste Orders Here")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To lr
        Select Case UCase(.Cells(r, "K").Value)
            Case "USD"
                Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = _
                  CDbl(.Cells(r, "L").Value * Sheets("Configuration").Range("V19").Value)
            Case "EUR"
                Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = _
                  CDbl(.Cells(r, "L").Value * Sheets("Configuration").Range("U19").Value)
            Case "GBP"
                Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = _
                  CDbl(.Cells(r, "L").Value * Sheets("Configuration").Range("W19").Value)
        End Select
    Next r
End With

With Sheets("Brightpearl")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 2 To lr
        Sheets("Brightpearl").Cells(r, "G") = _
            CDbl(.Cells(r, "G").Value / Cells(r, "F").Value)
    Next r
End With
```

Comment: we don't provide code here...[tour]

Answer (score 0):

Unless its a typo you need to add a period before the second reference to Cells

CDbl(.Cells(r, "G").Value / **Cells(r, "F")**.Value)